# How to write the received id from get_chat_members Pyrogram to a separate file?

Tags: python, pyrogram

How can I make it so that when parsing members in a group using the pyrogram library, it writes to a separate file, only the id or username of the user?

My code:

```
from pyrogram import Client

TARGET = -10011796008

app = Client("my_account")

async def main():
    async with app:
        async for member in app.get_chat_members(TARGET, limit=1):

app.run(main())
```

An example of what is written to the console:

```
{
    "_": "ChatMember",
    "status": "ChatMemberStatus.MEMBER",
    "user": {
        "_": "User",
        "id": 87453014,
        "is_self": false,
        "is_contact": false,
        "is_mutual_contact": false,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "is_bot": false,
        "is_verified": false,
        "is_restricted": false,
        "is_scam": false,
        "is_fake": false,
        "is_support": false,
        "first_name": "Niker",
        "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
        "username": "Zenixex"
    },
    "joined_date": "2022-03-19 23:22:18"`
```

I need "id": 87453014 which is written to a separate file in the console

Answer (score 0):

Select a specific value:

```
b = await app.get_users(chat_id)
print(f"{b.id} | {b.username}")


>>> 13911381 | qwerty123
```